# How to handle password Expired pop up in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, popup

I am working in asp.net using SQL server 2005.

In my web application  user name, password, Validity date like that i have three fields
for example:

- User name: reka
- password : reka123
- Validity date : 24-01-2013

It is working fine, but
suppose when you are logging into that form at this date `25-01-2013` ,  I want to show the pop up message  `Your Password Expired`. How do I tackle this?

Comment: what is the question exactly ? , do u want to know how to show a popup or you are asking about how to implement the whole functionality ?

Comment: I want to know functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you are only asking about determining if the current date is greater than the validation period date. then you can do :

```
if(DateTime.Today > validationPeriodDate)
{
 //Password expired
 //Redirect to change password screen
}
else
{
 //password is valid with valid validation period
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Habib ...  and i have i one more doubts insteated of date suppose i gave days that is 4 days like that then how to do?

Comment: @Reka999, if you store 4 days as validation period, then you need to have start date in your storage as well, then you can do : `startDate.AddDays(4) <= DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 0):

First : you need to design your database table as following ,

`ID` as `int`

`userName` as `varchar`

`password` as `varchar`

`ValidityDate` as `Date`

then use any ORM to create class of this table in your `asp.net` application , ORM like `linq-to-sql` , `entity framework` or you can just execute your sql query using `SqlConnection` , `SqlCommand` objects , check example here : [Example of using SqlCommand](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) 
, every time login select his `ValidityDate` from the database .

```
if (DateTime.Today > ValidityDate)
{

// password expired , there are many ways to show a popup 
// simple way a javascript alert
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "test", "   
    <script>alert('password expired!');</script>");

// check here for many jquery elegant popups  
   /*  http://collegegfx.com/10-best-jquery-popup-plugins/  */

}
else
{
//password not expired ,login
}
```